# INSERT INTO doesn't work in php codes

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question is sort of dumb but I can't find out where the problem is I checked it with the codes in documentation and similar codes in stackoverflow but I can't figure out the problem. 
this is my code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['buy'])) {
 $id = (int) $_POST['id'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $price = (int) $_POST['price'];
 date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
 $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
 $insquery = "INSERT INTO `purchases`  (file_id,     file_name, price, date) VALUES ({$id}, '{$name}', {$price}, {$date})";
 $insResult = mysqli_query($con, $insquery);
 if ($insResult) {
    //do sth
 } else {
     //do sth else
 }
```

I have tested these:
1- the post array is not empty and returns exactly those that I assigned to variables. 
2- I have a table called purchases and it configured properly because I insert data in SQL and get it back successfully.
3- I have tried on SQL statement without {} around SQL variables but no luck.

and another question is after the SQL statement done how can I use the `OUTPUT Inserted.ID` as a variable in PHP?
thanks in advance.

Comment: try to debug  $insResult = mysqli_query($con, $insquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));

Comment: Missing quotes in values. Better use prepare statement!!

Comment: Troubleshooting such things:  (1) check for errors returned from `mysql_query()`. (2) display the text of query from your php program right before you run it. (3) You probably need quote marks around the date information in your query.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() is a MySQL function yielding the most recently inserted autoincrement id.

Comment: Try to print insert query - echo $insquery and execute directly in phpmyadmin to check .

Comment: i get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'OUTPUT Inserted.ID (file_id, file_name, price, date) VALUES (1, 'طراحی وب' at line 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `date` is a keyword in MySql. So use backtick (`).

> INSERT INTO purchases (`file_id`, `file_name`, `price`,
>   `date`) ...

2. Instead of using direct substitution values, you could use below methods to avoid sql injection.

> Using MySQLi (for MySQL):
>
> ```
> $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
> $stmt->bind_param("sss", $firstname, $lastname, $email);
>
> // set parameters and execute
> $firstname = "John";
> $lastname = "Doe";
> $email = "john@example.com";
> $stmt->execute();
> ```
>
> Please refer [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

3. Use `mysqli::$insert_id` for last inserted ID ([Docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php))

Comment: *"date is a reserved keyword in MySql. So use backtick"* - That is false, it is just a "keyword" and not a "reserved" word; there is no "reserved keyword" term. Look for yourself https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - there is no `(R)` next to it. So please lose that misconception and pass on false information to others.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Thanks for your correction and i have updated my answer.